# vba how to insert dynamic parameters into SQL bulk syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to use vb opendialog to open a random csv file, and insert the data from the csv into SQL Server 2014. When it comes to hard-code data it seems fine, but for dynamic random upload it has problems. Quite stuck here so please help me.

This is my dynamic test code, and I already created the database and table and columns which match the file format and the column names of the csv file :

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim con As String = "Server=KEN-PC;Database=testData;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim openFileDialog2 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "c:\Desktop"
    openFileDialog2.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog2.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog2.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                ' Insert code to read the stream here.
                TextBox2.Text = openFileDialog2.FileName
                Dim conString As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

                Try
                    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
                        connection.ConnectionString = con
                        sql = "BULK INSERT cvtest
                        FROM" & "'constring'" & "With ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
                          ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"
                        connection.Open()
                        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
                        adapter.Fill(ds)

                        connection.Close()
                    End Using

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try

            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I execute it like a PHP way but it throws an error of unmatched columns, but I think that's not the case cause I already create the equal stuffs and I test it using hard-code data it replies me with success, Thank you for reading and hope for a advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha... I have solve it myself,  the key is the sql command cannot catch dynamic parameter I assigned, so therefore I do the following and it works

```
                        sql = "
                        BULK INSERT cvtest
                        FROM 'close' With ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
                          ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"
                        sql = sql.Replace("close", conString)
```